# How to center HelpProvider popup over a modal form?

Tags: c#

I added a HelpProvider to a modal form. The form is centered when shown using CenterToParent method.

When I hit the F1 key at runtime, the help string popup is shown in the bottom left corner of the screen and only the first part of the help string is shown -the rest is cut off at the edge of the screen.

```
string helpmsg="This is a demonstration of using the HelpProvider class    to show a help string" +
  "when the user hits the F1 key. I works except the help is shown in a box that is cut off in" +
 "the bottom left corner of the screen such that not all of the help is visible."

this.helpProvider1.SetHelpString(this, helpmsg);

this.helpProvider1.SetShowHelp(this, true);
```

Comment: is this winforms?

Comment: [Here's some documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.helpprovider(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Yes, Winforms. .Net 2.0